# Bash Square Bracket Expansion

Tags: bash

So the official bash manual states that "For example, the regular expression ‘[0123456789]’ matches any single digit, whereas ‘[^()]’ matches any single character that is not an opening or closing parenthesis,", copied a link at the bottom of this question, for context.

So I tested it every which way I could think of, to try and do the "negate" part of this, but I could not get it to work:

```
$ cat test
a line
b line
c line
d line
$ grep [^abc] test
a line
b line
c line
d line
$ grep '[^abc]' test
a line
b line
c line
d line
$ grep '[^(abc)]' test
a line
b line
c line
d line
[$ grep [^(abc)] test
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Character-Classes-and-Bracket-Expressions.html

I was expecting just line D to be shown

Comment: `[^(abc)]` is not a regular expression as seen from **bash**. It is a glob-pattern. See the section _Pathname Expansion_ in the bash man-page. The only place where bash interprets a regex, is to the right of the `=~` operator inside the `[[ ... ]]` command.

Comment: In addition, parenthesis have a special purpose in bash to denote commands run as a child process, and you can't use them at all in a pathname expansion pattern, unless you escape them.

Comment: Note that, in `grep [^abc] test`, the `[^abc]` will be interpreted as a glob pattern by **bash** and will match filenames which consist of a single character different from `a`, `b`, and `c`, if any. Regular expressions that are intended to be interpreted by **grep** must be quoted.

Comment: Side note: The `bash` tag is sort of wrong; this has something to do with regexps and `grep`, not with `bash`.

Answer (score 3):

`[^abc]` matches any character which is not `a`, `b`, or `c`.

It matches `a line` because it includes  , `l`, `i`, `n`, and `e`, none of which are the excluded characters.

To ensure that *no* character in the string matches any in the list you would need `grep '^[^abc]*$' test`

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that bash always considers whitespace.  How do I find out what it considers then?  I just read most of the bash ref guide and I can't see anywhere it mentioning that whitespace is considered.  I'm now wondering what else it considers.

Comment: This is about grep, not bash. The page you link to talks about *characters*, whitespace characters are characters (as are the letters in the word *line*)

Comment: Right, so basically ^ will end up creating more issues than it solves to be honest.  So your line says, if it starts with not a b or c, followed by anything, negate it.  It makes sense.  I guess people who write bash scripts must just always try and do a match, rather than a "not" match statement to avoid any headaches.  Am I right?

Comment: No, it says says that from the start of the line, match any number of characters that are not `a`, `b`, or `c`, until the end of the line. I'm not going to speculate on how other people who write bash scripts use grep.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I have one more question, because I'm confused.  My original [^abc] statement does still mean not a, b, or c, but then you say it re-matches these lines because they have a space in.  I don't understand the logic.  If you say not lines with a,b, or c, how can it then suddenly re-match them?  Like, by definition, lines with an a,b,c are already excluded before it decides to not exclude them.

Comment: No matter the logic eg: match whitespace and then not abc: OR if the logic was match not abc & then match whitespace, both should yield only line D.  So I don't get how it's not doing what I said it should do originally.

Comment: `[^abc]` matches **any** character which is not `a`, `b`, or `c`. If **any part** of the line matches the regular expression  then the line is matched. A space matches the expression. `l` matches the expression. `i` matches the expression. and so on.

Comment: If the line was `abcaaaa` and not `a line` then the line wouldn't match `[^abc]`

Comment: Try typing it into https://regex101.com/ and see which parts of your test data get highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

To stick with the `bash` tag on the question, here’s a pure Bash option that takes advantage of `extglob` (which is mostly enabled by default).

```bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  [[ "$line" = *([^abc]) ]] && printf '%s\n' "$line"
done < test
```

Comment: Are you sure `extglob` is enabled by default ? Can you check with `bash --norc -c "shopt -p extglob"` ?